# Spring Rest Template Injects Value into Parameter with %

Tags: java, spring, url, encoding

Can someone please explain to me what is happening in the following code?

If I run:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("header1", "data");
headers.add("header2", "data");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);

ResponseEntity<JSONObject> response = 
rest.exchange("https://example.com/../{username}/{path}", HttpMethod.GET, entity, JSONObject.class, "user%123", "path");
```

Spring tells me that the URL used is https://example.com/../username/path where username = user%25123 even though I set the username = user%123.

This is looking to me to be not a Spring issue, rather a URL encoding issue, but can anyone tell me where this extra 25 comes from?

Comment: It is not a URL encoding *issue*, because the `%` sign is *supposed* to be encoded as `%25`. It would only be an issue if the `%` sign hadn't been encoded. The issue here seems to be your understanding of how URLs work, when they contain *special* characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%25` is a URL-encoded percent sign, so `user%123` encodes to `user%25123`

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP